# Is it possible to configure the h2o.ai automl with a vector response

Tags: h2o

I've been working with the h2o.ai automl function on a few problems with quite a bit of success, but have come across a bit of a roadblock.

I've got a problem that uses 500-odd predictors (all float) to map onto 6 responses (again all float.)

> Required Data Parameters
>
> y: This argument is the name (or index) of the response column.

[3.16 docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html#required-data-parameters)

It seems that the automl library only handles a single response. Am I missing something? Perhaps in the terminology even?

In the case that I'm not, my plan is to build 6 separate leaderboards, one for each response, and use the results to kick-start a manual network search.

In theory I guess I could actually run the 6 automl models individually to get the vector response, but that feels like an odd approach.

Any insight would be appreciated,
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Not just AutoML, but H2O generally, will only let you predict a single thing.

Without more information about what those 6 outputs represent, and their relationship to each other, I can think of 3 approaches.

**Approach 1:** 6 different models, as you suggest.

**Approach 2:** Train an auto-encoder to compress 6 dimensions to 1 dimension. Then train your model to predict that single value. Then expand it back out. (E.g. by a lookup table on the training data, e.g. if your model predicts 1.123, and you have [1,2,3,4,5,6] was represented by 1.122, and [3.14,0,0,3.14,0,0] was represented by 1.125, you could choose [1,2,3,4,5,6], or a weighted average of those 2 closest matches.)  (Other dimension-reduction approaches, such as PCA, are the same idea.)

**Approach 3:** If the possible combinations of your 6 floats is a (relatively small) finite set, you could have an explicit lookup table, to N categories.

I assume each are continuous variables, which is why they are float, so I expect approach 3 will be inferior to approach 2. If there is very little correlation/relationship between the 6 outputs, approach 1 is going to be best.

Comment: The 6 outputs represent a particular dimension reduction mapping that I want to model.

As such, they should be very independent, so the 'Approach 1' looks like the best option.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PaulHannah If it is a 500 to 6 dimension reduction that you are after, have you tried simply using an autoencoder (which is designed to do exactly that)? h2o.automl might be the wrong tool for the job?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I have given that a go, but ran into a couple of problems. First is the sheer amount of computation required to get there. The other is that we're looking for a particular mapping that emphasises particular features.